# Excel bar chart: Plot some categories (not series) on a secondary axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to produce a bar chart that shows the change in 6 variables over two periods. 5 of the variables are percentages, so they are bounded at 100%. The other variable, "number of committee members", is a small integer (unbounded). Therefore it doesn't make sense to normalize the committee members by expressing them as a percentage. But I would like to show all 6 variables in one plot.

Excel charts allow you to specify a secondary axis for some series. Is there a way to use a secondary axis for different variables/categories?

Currently my chart looks like:

[image: Current chart]

And I would like the final 5 categories to get a percentage axis.

Answer (score 3):

Only whole series can be plotted on the secondary axis. But with clever data layout, it can be made to look as if it was just a specific category.

[image]

format the gray and yellow to match the colors of the other series, then remove the legend entries. Format the secondary axis as percentage.